# How to Creating a custom Splash Screen Implementing the Splash Screen interface in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, splash-screen

Could you please give me a practical example?
I don't understand this clearly.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen#implement-the-splashscreen-interface

```
    private MySplashView mySplashView;

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public View createSplashView(
      @NonNull Context context,
      @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
       
        mySplashView = new MySplashView(context);
        return mySplashView;
    }

    @Override
    public void transitionToFlutter(@NonNull Runnable onTransitionComplete) {
        
        mySplashView.animateAway(onTransitionComplete);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this package => https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen

1). add the below dependency in pubsec.yaml and then call `$ flutter pub get` in terminal

```
dependencies:
  splashscreen: ^1.3.5
```

2). And then fallow the below Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new SplashScreen(
      seconds: 14,
      navigateAfterSeconds: new AfterSplash(),
      title: new Text(
        'Welcome In SplashScreen',
        style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),
      ),
      image: new Image.network(
          'https://flutter.io/images/catalog-widget-placeholder.png'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      loaderColor: Colors.red,
    );
  }
}

class AfterSplash extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Welcome In SplashScreen Package"),
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text(
          "Succeeded!",
          style: new TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Example copy from => https://pub.dev/packages/splashscreen/example